# Does Snowflake insert “OVERWRITE” impact how STREAMs capture changes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
insert OVERWRITE into table1 
select * from table2 where City = SFO
```

I noticed that Snowflake STREAM captured all rows of the table instead of just City=SFO

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is normal behaviour. Whats your question?

Comment: I am only overwriting slice of the data only SFO (other cities data is to be retained) . I was expecting stream to only capture what was overwritten

Comment: never mind Morning coffee issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert overwrite deletes all rows from table1 , so the stream is  capturing all deleted   rows plus the inserted rows in table 1 with city=SFO from table2.

Comment: Biraja, but overwrite didn’t delete all rows in table 1 , only overwrites new rows ? But stream captured all rows

Comment: `INSERT OVERWRITE` completely replaces the records of TABLE1 with the records of the `SELECT`.

Comment: thanks guys, mistake on my end its pretty much truncate and load